# How to pass Django formset form variable to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-forms

Basically I am using formsets, each form has a form ID and a deleted button amongst other things.
When the delete button is clicked i'd like to call a function and pass the form ID to it, how can i achieve this?

```
{% for form in formset %}

{{ form.form_id_test }}

<button id="delete-form" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" 
onclick="deleteFormFunc({{ form.form_id_test }})">
    Delete Form
</button>

{% endfor %}
```

I am not able to pass the arguments like this, basically syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the form id of a formset form  with form.id, eg,

```
{% for form in formset %}
    ...onclick="deleteFormFunc('{{ form.id }}')">...
{% endfor %}
```

...which should be a string value like 'id_form-1-id' that you can use in document.getElementById() in your deleteFormFunc

Answer (score 0):

```
    ...onclick="deleteFormFunc(this.id)">...
```

`this.id` will get the id of the tag it is encoded in.